# GNOME automatically switching to the window selection screen

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, activities-overview

Extra GNOME-noob here as you can imagine from the question:

GNOME is constantly switching to the 'window selection screen' with blinking circles on the upper left corner, and it's doing it so frequently I can't even work properly.

[image: .]

I can't figure out what it's trying to notify me about, nothing is happening both on other windows or workspaces, could you help me?

Comment: In my case the activities overview appears even without hovering the panel. At this point I think something might have been broken by some extension, but after installing [No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) as suggested in that question's answer it should be ok now. Thank you.