# Show all open windows / Activities overview in Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME - how to disable some ways to produce it?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, activities-overview

It sometimes occurs at my laptop that all open windows are shown at "random" moment and I am not able to find the reason (and it is quite annoying).

I know that I can get the "show all windows" / "Activities overview" feature by pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key on my keyboard or by clicking the **Activities** at the left upper corner (which is fine and I like that).

I have already disabled '*Activities Overview Hot Corner*' in **Tweaks**.

Anyway, sometimes I move my mouse and this "show all windows" feature is activated and I do not know why. Any idea, what may be the reason?

I have read [GNOME automatically switching to the window selection screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033689/gnome-automatically-switching-to-the-window-selection-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [GNOME shows activities overview when mouse hover dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984705/gnome-shows-activities-overview-when-mouse-hover-dash) and [Activities corner keeps "re-enabling" itself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033739/activities-corner-keeps-re-enabling-itself), but they seem to me to be similar issues (the same result), but not the same way to produce it.

I use Ubuntu 18.04 with default GNOME.

**Update:** May it be related to this message that occurred on my screen today?

[image]

Comment: May it be related to this message that occurred on my screen today? https://imgur.com/a/yjyrukk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the '**[Activities Configurator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/)**' GNOME shell extension evident from the screenshot. To work properly the extension needs the '*Activities Overview Hot Corner*' option in *Tweaks* turned **on**.

So launch Tweaks and enable the '*Activities Overview Hot Corner*' option. Then go to the '*Extensions*' section and open the settings for Activities Configurator. Disable the '*Activities Overview Hot Corner*' option from here.